# Handle file requests

Tags: files, .htaccess

I'd like to be able to intercept calls to files (.pdf for instance) in order to run some custom code before the user accesses/downloads the file, and add a cover page accordingly.

From what I understand this can't be done by Drupal alone, and requires some server-side configurations as well. Could anyone guide me towards a solution and/or the hook to intercept file downloads? (hook_file_download seems appropriate on the first glance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `hook_file_download()` is the one you want to implement, assuming you're using the [private file system](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file). The docs have examples of how to use that hook.

There's no built-in way to do this (at least no way that involves Drupal) for public files, as those are served directly at the web server level without the application ever getting involved.

You'll be able to implement a solution for public files based on modifying the .htaccess file to *not* pass those files straight through, and implement your own path system similar to the core private files one; the particular functionality will obviously depend on your exact requirements, if you decide to go this route I'd recommend spending some time looking at the core system and file modules to see how the mechanism is implemented.

Unfortunately it's not a few-lines-of-code job so I can't provide an example, it's something you'll have to put together yourself.

Comment: Clive, gave you a check since this solved my issue (private/hook_file_download). Only one question though if you don't mind. In my hook_file_download, I pretty much create a temp file, which is the original PDF plus a conditional coverpage, which I need to ouput to the browser. Thing is that hook_file_download is used to check for access so I can't return the file I produced. The thing that works is to output the file and perform a drupal_exit or a die, but that seems brutal and produces a broken favicon as well. Any suggestion? Is there any other hook that's more appropriate? Thanks.

Comment: You could theoretically override the page callback for system/file/% in a menu alter, which would give you carte blanche to do exactly what you want with the request. But you'd be reproducing a bunch of code, and it'd need thorough testing to make sure you're not interfering with core functionality. Personally I'd just bail out and pass the temp file straight through like you're already doing.

Comment: Aha. I see, and what about that pesky favicon? :P In my local environment I see the X from Xampp and it is driving me crazy, hehe.

Comment: Not sure to be honest, maybe you're not outputting the right headers for the file, so the connection is getting prematurely severed and the favicon not being requested? Difficult to without having the code in front of me I'm afraid

Comment: Yeah, sounds plausible. I understand, don't worry :) Thanks!